# How would I add keyframes to my animation clip from another object in Unity?

Tags: unity, animation, animator

I am creating an FPS game which will have many weapons that have their own animations. I will need to access keyframes of the character's position, rotation, and scale, how will I do that? I can only add keyframes from the object I'm animating, or, I can only add keyframes from a child object.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just animated the character itself and made the gun a child lol.

Comment: This answer might be more useful to other developers in the future if you edit it to include a more detailed step-by-step breakdown of how you solved this. Pictures often help!